# sending data to a particular thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

My application has a singleton class (communicating with a serial COM port) that handles data requisitions from multiple threads. While its request is being processed, the threads should `wait()`. How can I notify a thread that the data is ready (and send it back) without waking all the waiting threads?

Comment: If you are not required to use Java 1.4, you should use objects from `java.util.concurrent` and not use `wait/notify`.

Comment: I'd use a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) - use `take` on the queue to have threads wait until data is ready

Comment: Singletons is a nightmare in multithreding programming.

Comment: is anybody still required to use java 1.4? :)

Comment: `ThreadPoolExecutor` may be another altervative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one [blocking queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for every threads and inject them into your Singleton. When any answer arrives, just pick the appropriate thread's queue and put the message with the offer(E o) method into it.

In your thread with the take() method you can wait to the answer for infinite time or use poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) for the timeboxed  waiting.

You can use an additional [concurrent queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) to feed the singleton without blocking it.

Answer (score 2):

While @Lexandro has a good answer, a simpler alternative that meets your requirements (as I understand them, thread waiting/blocking is o.k.) is to just synchronize the method in the static class.

Comment: I agree with you, but I personally prefer solutions without usages of synchronized blocks/methods.

Comment: I tried a similar solution wich didn't worked.The cause was there's a single `serialPortActionListener`wich receives all data. But each packet is adressed to a particular thread (as threads ask for data from radio transmiters, that send back their adress so i can channel the data to the right clients). As i see it, there's a single instance of the `serialPortActionListener` that needs to redirect data to specific threads. So I need to keep reference to each thread  somehow.